Will Cosmos DB continuation token really stop working if I upgrade to a newer Cosmos DB client SDK?
Will Cosmos DB continuation token really stop working if I upgrade to a newer Cosmos DB client SDK?
According to this documentation

As long as you're using the same SDK version, continuation tokens never expire.

So what happens when I have a REST API that exposes the continuation tokens and the API got updated while the client is going through the pages?
Let's say:

API client calls my REST API.
REST API returns items and continuation token for the next page.
REST API with a newer Cosmos DB SDK gets deployed.
API client calls my new REST API with the continuation token.

Will Cosmos DB accept the continuation token from the old Cosmos DB SDK?

This seems like an extreme edge case, no? 1) SDK versions are not a frequently-changing thing; and 2) if it's your app, you control when you update it. Also: how are you going to update your app, in-place, in the middle of a query?

As the documentation says, there is no guarantee. There are cases where the query execution engine might have new features and have different format.
Not all SDK versions have these type of changes but they can, for example, SDK 3.38.0 -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/changelog.md#-3380---2024-01-31, hence the statement that the only way to be sure the query can continue executing is if the continuation is processed by the same version the token was obtained from. It might work, but there's no guarantee. I would make sure to check the changelog for any breaking changes notices.
Normally if the token cannot be parsed, you'd get a CosmosException with BadRequest (400) StatusCode.

Thanks for your answer. In your example, the release notes documented a way to deploy new the SDKs version in a way that's temporarily compatible with old SDKs. Disabling ODE basically allows me to run both SDK versions side by side.
What I'm concerned about is what if there is no way to run two SDK version side-by-side? Will this ever happen? The implication is, if I don't want any downtime when upgrading my REST API, I basically need to temporarily run both versions of my REST API side-by-side and routes requests to the correct version while my client's transition to the new REST API.
